# Django passing foreign key to form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to django.

I need to take the id from the request and when the form is created I want it to make the value of complaintid field from this value and rest from form itself.

models.py

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
    complaintid= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    dateofcomplaint=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    policestation= models.CharField(max_length=120)
    location=models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.complaintid)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.complaintid
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("crimefiles:detail", kwargs={"id":self.complaintid}) 

class Fir(models.Model):
    firid=models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
    complaintid=models.ForeignKey(Complaint,default=None)
    signedby= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content=models.TextField(default="First Information Report")

    def  __unicode__(self):
        return self.firid

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firid
```

views.py

```
def fir_create(request,id=None):
    form =FirForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request,"sucessfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect()
    context={
    "form":form
    }
    return render(request,"fir_form.html",context)
```

forms.py

```
class FirForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Fir
        fields=[
        "firid",
        "signedby",
        "content"]
```

Comment: I want to add the complaint id from the url and set it to the form and take the rest of the values form the form ..in fir form   in fir_create function im passing id .. i want to use it to save as complaint id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already saving with `commit=False`, you just need to set the complaint field before calling `instance.save()`.

You can use `get_object_or_404` to make sure that `id` is a valid complaint id.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def fir_create(request,id=None):
    if id is not None:
        complaint = get_object_or_404(Complaint, id=id)
    else:
        complaint = None
    form =FirForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.complaint = complaint
        instance.save()
        ...
```

Note that you might need to add more validation. - at the moment users could change the complaint just by changing the id in the url.

Comment: okay thanks i finally figured it out.

Comment: @OlowuAbayomi Glad you figured it out