# Passing Authenticated User into Model View in Django

Tags: python, django, view, model

I am creating a profile model that needs to pass the current authenticated user as the foreign key. If I do not exclude the user field, I can select from all the users, but I need to hide this field and pass the current authenticated user automatically when the form is submitted. Additional fields like name, dob, etc. will be added to the model by the user. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add the user to the model form. What I have in my views.py file (below) is the closest I have been able to get.

***Models***

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank = True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_photos/', blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

***Views***

```
class ProfileCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    model = Profile
    template_name = 'account/profile_creation.html'
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'profile_photo']
    login_url = 'account_login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.save()
        return super(ProfileCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

***Forms***

```
class CustomProfileForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:

        model = Profile
```

The error I am getting:

null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (16, first name, last name, dob,  , null).

Comment: self.object.save(user=user)

Comment: Thanks for the input mehedi. I added self.object.save(user=user) to the def form_valid function and it now throws a: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user' error

Comment: def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        self.object.user= user
        self.object.save()
        return super(ProfileCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

Comment: AttributeError at /accounts/profile/create/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user' error on the self.object.user=user line it looks like

Comment: I am using a custom user model and have the unique identifier set to email, so is it an issue where I need to be passing the email and I am asking for the wrong thing?

Comment: try this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642934/django-passing-foreign-key-to-form

Comment: Still can’t get it to work. Would love some additional guidance here.

Comment: def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(ProfileCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

try this.
ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

Comment: I was able to get it with the link you provided, thank you very much!